# Angular 2+: how to jump to an anchor?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I'd like to use the **angular router** to jump/scroll to a certain fragment (hash). The URL is generated correctly as `/#section5`, but nothing happens on click.

After searching a lot, I found many people ([e.g.](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595)) with the same problem, a few workarounds, but no proper solution. I expected this to be a basic core feature.

The following code does not work:

```
<!-- Link --> 
<a routerLink="/" fragment="section5" routerLinkActive="active">Section 5</a>

<!-- Target -->
<div id="section5">Section 5 here</div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/kzZ2VR/ refer this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `scrollIntoView`, add below code in your component's constructor

```
router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    const tree = router.parseUrl(router.url);
    if (tree.fragment) {
      const element = document.querySelector("#" + tree.fragment);
      if (element) { element.scrollIntoView(true); }
    }
  }
});
```